# Typescript: Create Type for library Class Method

Tags: typescript

There's many cases where I want to create *helper types* based on Class Methods (usually provided from library classes). But I can't quite seem to figure it out.

Ideally something like the following would be great. But it doesn't seem to work in this case.

```js
// Library code
declare class LibClass {
  Method1(something: number): Promise<string>;
}
// My application code
type LibMethodType = ReturnType<LibClass.Method1>
```

Does anyone have any suggestions on how to solve this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Okay I found the answer by looking at the ts-error. Here's how to achieve this:

```js
declare class LibClass {
  Method1(something: number): string;
}

// Needs to
type LibMethodType = LibClass['Method1']

const myFunction: LibMethodType = (s: number) => s.toString()
```

It's also important that you use the `LibClass['Method1']` syntax rather than `LibClass.Method1`

[image]